# Mongo doesn't save data into disk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongorito

In our project we often have a problem when mongo doesn't save its state into disk, and after rebooting the application we lose data. I could not determine when and why this happens - somehow and somewhen :). Does anybody know how to synchronize mongodb storage to disk with some api? We use mongorito ODM. PLeasure to hear any variants.

Some details. 
Mongo version 3.2.
Application - it is an electron application. Under the hood it uses mongo as  storage - we use mongo on client side and install it as a windows service advantagely. Application starts, makes different transactions, read/write data from/to mondo db - nothing strange. When we close this application and reopen next time - we cannot find last rows (documents) in some collections that were succesfully (according to mongo answers) saved. We have no errors. 
Can anyone explain what the write concern is and how to setup it not to wait 60 seconds before flushing the data - may be this is the reason?

Some code of db connect/disconnect. `app` means an electron application:

```
const {Database} = require('mongorito');

const db = new Database(__DBPATH__);
db.connect();

db.register(__MONGORITO_MODEL__);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    db.disconnect();
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really a question that can be answered here, with what you've provided. As written, this is unclear and too broad: there's no code, no errors, just a general description of the problem.

Comment: MongoDB with the WiredTiger storage engine will flush data to disk every 60 seconds. I second the other commenters here that there's not enough information in your question to be able to even guess at what happened. At the very least you should describe your deployment, your MongoDB version, and any error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the write concern setting within your application and make sure it's set to the requirements of your business - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

Also, make sure you're running a replica set in your production environment

Comment: I doubt write concern is the issue, if they have no data on disk (nor is running a replicaset). Seems like they have a more fundamental issue, which is impossible to diagnose without more details. Probably best not to offer suggestions without knowing more. Could be a coding error. Could be a MongoDB config issue. Could be anything.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I assumed with the statement "save its state into disk, and after rebooting the application we lose data" that they could query the data back, but I agree it is very vague.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I've edited my question. Has it became clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyboy, I've solved the problem. The reason was the journaling. I turn on the journaling for mongodb service and the problem has gone.

`mongod.exe --journal`